# OpenGL 3.3 for Intel HD Graphics in Debian?

Tags: debian, graphics-card, intel-graphics, opengl

I'm using **OpenGL 3.0** with **Mesa 10.3.2** in **Debian 8.1** Jessie by system default, but I need **OpenGL 3.3** and I don't know how to enable it. I tried to update Mesa but it's still with OpenGL 3.0.

This is the output of **glxinfo | grep OpenGL**:

> OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
>   OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile
>   OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.2
>   OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
>   OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
>   OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
>   OpenGL core profile extensions:
>   OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
>   OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
>   OpenGL context flags: (none)
>   OpenGL extensions:
>   OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
>   OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.0
>   OpenGL ES profile extensions:

CPU info:

> processor : 0
>   vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
>   cpu family  : 6
>   model       : 58
>   model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 1000M @ 1.80GHz
>   stepping    : 9
>   microcode   : 0x17
>   cpu MHz     : 1279.968
>   cache size  : 2048 KB
>   physical id : 0
>   siblings    : 2
>   core id     : 0
>   cpu cores   : 2
>   apicid      : 0
>   initial apicid  : 0
>   fpu     : yes
>   fpu_exception   : yes
>   cpuid level : 13
>   wp      : yes
>   flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
>   bogomips    : 3592.01
>   clflush size    : 64
>   cache_alignment : 64
>   address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
>   power management:
>   
>   processor   : 1
>   vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
>   cpu family  : 6
>   model       : 58
>   model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 1000M @ 1.80GHz
>   stepping    : 9
>   microcode   : 0x17
>   cpu MHz     : 1282.640
>   cache size  : 2048 KB
>   physical id : 0
>   siblings    : 2
>   core id     : 1
>   cpu cores   : 2
>   apicid      : 2
>   initial apicid  : 2
>   fpu     : yes
>   fpu_exception   : yes
>   cpuid level : 13
>   wp      : yes
>   flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
>   bogomips    : 3592.01
>   clflush size    : 64
>   cache_alignment : 64
>   address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
>   power management:

Comment: Are you positive your hardware even supports OpenGL 3.3?  I noticed two things, first [Mesa 10.3.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_(computer_graphics)) already supports OpenGL 3.3, and second Mesa 10.5.x is the current version.  So if you are only able to use OpenGL 3.0 it means its a hardware limitation.  Clarify what hardware you have so I can submit an answer.

Comment: I have Intel HD Graphics. Not a dedicated GPU like nvidia or ATI, on Intel Celeron 1000M CPU.

Comment: I know that.  You literally provided at least that much in the question itself.  You should update your question to include the CPU information.  What about my other question?  I still need to know if the hardware even supports OpenGL 3.3.  The version of Mesa you have installed already supports OpenGL 3.3

Comment: So the [hardware](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/23885/eng/ReleaseNotes_GFX_64.pdf) itself supports OpenGL 4.0.  Which means this is a driver problem more then likely.  I would simply update Mesa to the current version.  Be sure you update the question with all relevant information.  The output of the command indicates you are already using the OpenGL 3.3 profile.  I am confused about what the problem is exactly

Comment: Yeah, I readed that my graphics card supports OpenGL 4.0. In another post I readed how to enable OpenGL 3.3 with Intel HD using a Ubuntu repository, but it won't work for Debian. 

Upgraded to Mesa 10.5.5 from sid packages, still with OpenGL 3.0 profile. Updated the first post with all the CPU information.

Comment: Where do you see you are using the OpenGL 3.0 profile because the output you supplied us indicates you are using the OpenGL 3.3 profile.

Comment: That's the core profile version. The version string readed by any program that requires OpenGL is "OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2" (8th line).

Answer (score 0):

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.2
```

You have OpenGL 3.3 already...